# Binding ngModel to expression's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I have a scenario in which the property ng-model should bind to value that comes from database as a part of business logic.

For simplicity, I have created this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15325/)

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.field1 = "PropertyFromDB";
    $scope.PropertyFromDB = "hello world";
}

<div ng-app>
  <h2>ngModel BINDING EXAMPLE</h2><br/>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <div ng-init="imod = field1">
          <input type="text" ng-model="imod"></input>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, `field1` is the value which will be property that comes from DB (i.e. PropertyFromDB) and ng-model should bind to PropertyFromDB instead of field1.
So, its like I want to evaluate expression inside expression syntax of ng-model but I am unable to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* refer to the current scope with `this` and read its property, like:

```
<div ng-init="imod = field1">
  <input type="text" ng-model="this[imod]"></input>
</div>
```

but it is a very unusual and inconvenient way to create a View Model.

I suggest creating a better structure/object that contains the field/value combination and setting that object on the scope, instead of setting field and value separately the scope.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for. The example above is strip down version of my actual implementation so field and value are separately on scope. Basically i was trying to accomplish something like this:-
<input type="text" ng-model="{{field1}}"></input>
But ng-model won't allow, expression in the value passed so i had to take ng-init route. If there are any better ways to achieve this please let me know. Thank you once again.

Comment: @miztaken, you don't need the `ng-init` here at all - same could be accomplished with `this[field1]`. But moreover, why the need to set the value right on the scope and not create an object as [suggested by @pankajparkar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29996113/968155)? And if you must, why make it the value name itself depend on the value of `field1` - why not call it statically `value1`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I kept the value right on the scope just for demo purpose. My business logic determines which field the ngModel should map to, for example purpose i have coded it on scope level and that is the reason i cant keep it static. Thank you for your help. This is how I am going to use it http://jsfiddle.net/miztaken/ns0utq9b/

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot set value of `ng-model` by using any expression. The alternative would be to change the stucture of the JSON which you returned from server.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="field in properties">
        <label>{{field.property}}</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="field.value" />
    </div>{{properties}}
</div>
```

**Code**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.properties = [{
        property: 'PropertyFromDB',
        value: "hello world"
    }, {
        property: 'PropertyFromDB1',
        value: "hello world1"
    }]
}
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15325/)

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thank you for the reply. I think this will not work because in your example ng-model is still directly bound to field.value not the property pointed by field.value.  I want ng-model to bind to property pointed out by value of field1, which is PropertyFromDB. So, basically i am trying to do something like this:-
<input type="text" ng-model="{{field1}}"></input>